# ROI solver that is applicable for a general objective function (F_objective) and binary variables

Tags: r, optimization, binary, roi

Is there any ROI solver in R that is applicable for a general (nonlinear) objective function (F_objective) and binary variables?

Comment: check to see if the lpSolve package gives you what you are looking for

Comment: @Jim no that is for linear models only.